# Fresco load image from sdcard

Tags: android, xamarin, fresco

I'm using fresco library and i'm trying to read an image from sd card into an imageview.

```
 var CatalogCategories = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString(), "dbsoft");
                SimpleDraweeView draweeView = FindViewById<SimpleDraweeView>(Resource.Id.MainImageView);
                Android.Net.Uri imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(CatalogCategories, "Main.jpg"));// For files on device
                draweeView.SetImageURI(imageUri);
```

I'm getting error Unable t oconvert instance of type androd.widget.imageview to type Com.Facebook.Drawee.View.SimpleDraweeView

If  i will change Imageview to

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/MainImageView" />
```

then i'm getting error

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!

Comment: what is SimpleDraweeView?  Does that inherit from ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error already tells you what you need to do: Initialize Fresco by calling `Fresco.initialize(...)` in your application, e.g.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fresco.initialize(this);
  }
}
```

More info: http://frescolib.org/docs/